Source for a day for Hashem equaling 1,000 years for us
Where is the source for the idea that a day for Hashem equals 1,000 years for us and what does it mean exactly (Hashem doesn't have "days", at least I don't know what that would even mean)? Is the concept used in places besides the six days of creation?

As Ezra stated, the reference given in the sources for this concept is Tehillim 90:4.
Derech Mitzvotecha Haamanut Elokut 12 explains that from above Atzilut, there is no "order of time" per se, all of time is as one. As we procede to the Sefirot of Atzilut, this unified time starts to divide. The first division is into 6 parts, each 1,000 years long (each of the 6 emotional attributes of Atzilut is the source of each 1,000 years, and the order of time arises from the fact that there is an order of Sefirot - see the source for more information). This is "Hashem's time", because the Sefirot of Atzilut represent, from our point of view, the "perspective" of Hashem, so to speak.
These further divide and divide until we get the continuum of time as we know it on the material plane. Picture, if you will, time as an upside down tree with one trunk, and then 6 branches, and these branches divide and divide and divide, and on the bottom level we have the flow of time we experience in our world.
Is it used in other places other than the 6 days of creation? It is used in Midrash Tanchuma VaYeshev 4 to explain that the Torah preceded the world by 2,000 years, due to combining Tehillim 90:4's logic with Mishlei 8:31:

[The Torah] was reared by Him and was His play thing day by day

2 days = 2,000 years.

The source comes from Moses:

For a thousand years are in Your eyes like yesterday, which passed, and a watch in the night. (Psalm 90:4)


This seems more like hyperbole to me

@Seeker to you perhaps, but this is what the Holy Torah writes. Refer to the commentary of the Steinsaltz: Indeed, a thousand years in Your eyes are like yesterday gone by. Time, as we know it, is irrelevant to G-d. For Him, a thousand years are like a day gone by; they leave no trace of palpable experience but only memory.

@Shmuel I have no problem accepting that it isn't hyperbole. Simply linking to a text in Tehillim doesn't prove that it isn't hyperbole. If commentaries (such as the one you referenced) say it is literal, I don't mind accepting that.

That line, as written, puts a limit on God.

Who deleted my comment here, and why, lol?

Traditionally, the book of Psalms is said to be written by David, not Moses.
And the way I understand that verse, it doesn't put an upper limit on G-d's time factor, as time since "yesterday" can be anything from a full 47 hours and 59 minutes and 59 seconds (start of yesterday to end of today) to a tiny amount of time (end of yesterday to start of today), it does imply that 1 day counted by G-d is usually at least 500 years by our counting.
As G-d can vary His speed at will, this also makes the 6 day creation in Genesis 1 consistent with the conception of the modern cosmological and evolutionary timeline as reported by many faithful scientists .  It even allows G-d to temporarily slow down to human speed to have conversations with Adam, Abraham, Israel and others, while also giving attention to believers created near other stars.
Just as G-d told Jakob a way to rear additional black sheep during the stay with Laban, He could equally have given a command for all the land based animals to evolve on Earth while He spent most of that day creating a nature in many other places .
Human counting of years didn't become accurate until late in the first scroll of the Torah, thus the seemingly impossible lifespans of early humans written there, while the time before Adam is known only from what G-d has told us from His perspective.  Just as a herder of sheep does not control the placement of each straw in the mouths of the flock, G-d need not have adjusted every word about time in the Torah to reflect an accurate count of human years between events.

This particular psalm opens תפלה למשה A prayer of Moses
